# Add header to listview

Tags: android, listview

In my `baseAdapter`, I want to add a header for my listview dynamically. I'm using multiple views so I want to add a header for each view. How can I do it?
This is what I do in my base adapter to get different views/layouts:

```
if (item == "fruits")) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, null)
    ...
//add header for this listview
} else if (item == "objects")) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, null)
    ...
//add header for this listview
} else if (item == "animals")) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, null)
    ...
    //add header for this listview
}
```